# Arabic issue with pisa in django

Tags: django

I have created a pdf with python pisa , but is not showing arabic characters even though i have added utf 8 encoding

```
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode('UTF-8')), result)
    if not pdf.err:
       user_msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, "PFA",  settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL ,[user_email])
       user_msg.attach("order.pdf",result.getvalue(),'application/pdf')
       user_msg.send()
```

please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is somebody with a similar problem and a solution: http://toolpart.hu/blog/2010/04/19/pisa-xhtml2pdf-utf-encoding-problem/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode('UTF-8')), result,  encoding='UTF-8')
```

;-)