# Django xhtml2pdf Arabic text not supporting

Tags: python, django, html-to-pdf, xhtml2pdf, pisa

I am using Django xhtml2pdf to generate PDF, and it not supporting Arabic text I tried all possible ways which are suggested but still no luck

```
<style>
        @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Markazi+Text);
        
        .markazi-text{font-family:'Markazi Text',serif}

        *{
            font-size: 12px;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        table{
            border: 1px solid #000;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
        table tr th{
            padding-top: 5px;
            -pdf-word-wrap: CJK;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        table tr td{
            padding-top: 5px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            width: auto;
            word-break: break-all;
            padding: 5px;
            -pdf-word-wrap: CJK;
        }
        table tr td p{
            word-break: break-all;
        }
        p{
            margin: 0px;
            font-family:'Markazi Text';
        }
        .vendor-sec{
            border: 1px solid #000;
            width: 150px;
            padding: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
    </style>
```

Django code

```
template_path = 'pdf.html'
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="declaration.pdf"'
    html = render_to_string(template_path, data)
    result = io.BytesIO()
    
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(io.BytesIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), dest=result,encoding='UTF-8')
    content = result.getvalue()

    encoded = base64.b64encode(content)
    encoded = encoded.decode('utf-8')
```

I tried all below solutions

1. [solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825133/arabic-issue-with-pisa-in-django)
2. [solution 2](https://github.com/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf/issues/345)
3. [solution 3](https://github.com/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf/issues/494)
4. [solution 4](https://github.com/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf/issues/72)

On HTML I can see arabic text but when I try to convert this HTML to pdf the its show blocks[image]